# Android AsyncTask blocks UI thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` for performing some database operations. The problem is when I execute the `AsyncTask` on `ThreadPoolExecutor` the UI thread getting blocked. Here is my code:

```
private class AddToQueue extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        int qLength = 0;    

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (db == null) return null;
            db.delete(DBHelper.QUEUETABLE, null, null);
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i < qLength; i++) {
                cv.put(DBHelper.INDEX, i);
                cv.put(DBHelper.PATH, items.get(i).getPath());
                cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, items.get(i).getTitle());
                try {
                    db.insert(DBHelper.QUEUETABLE, null, cv);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cv.clear();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) { }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            qLength = list.getAdapter().getCount();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) { }
```

Comment: How are you executing the `AsyncTask`? Also what you are doing with  `qLength` is not quite thread safe.

Comment: I just hope you 're not calling doInBackground manually

Comment: How do you know it is getting blocked? Can you execute it on a regular pool?

Comment: When you're executing an AsyncTask all you have to do is:
`AddToQueue task = new AddToQueue();` and right after that:
`task.execute(args);` where args is whats passed into `doInBackground`

Comment: Executed on serial executor, replaced qLength with static number. but the result is same.

Comment: When i remove the line db.insert(DBHelper.QUEUETABLE, null, cv); . it works fine.

Comment: Same behavior when i run this code inside an IntentService. Problem is in this line db.insert(DBHelper.QUEUETABLE, null, cv);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. Just replaced

```
 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
 for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
     c.moveToPosition(i);
     cv.put(DBHelper.INDEX, i);
     cv.put(DBHelper.PATH, c.getString(0));
     cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, c.getString(1));
     try {
         // db.insert(DBHelper.QUEUETABLE, null, cv);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     cv.clear();
```

with this one

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.QUEUETABLE + "(" +
                      DBHelper.INDEX + ", " + DBHelper.PATH + ", " +
                      DBHelper.TITLE + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
 db.beginTransaction();
 SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
 for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
     c.moveToPosition(i);
     stmt.bindString(1, i + "");
     stmt.bindString(2, c.getString(0));
     stmt.bindString(3, c.getString(1));
     stmt.execute();
     stmt.clearBindings();
 }
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: @Sujth have you tried with a lot of records (10.000>)? Because I use SQLiteStatement too but I have the "block UI thread" problem...